# Dropkick and organinctabs

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-dropkick

Im using dropkick on a site and it works really well and looks great. However when I try to use it within a tab (organinc tabs) the dropkick data is on sent.
Any ideas why this may be happening and solutions would be greatly appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that dropkick is not intiated on a hidden div. You can use Jquery to activate dropkick once the tab in question is selected.